# Kernel update required 2 reboot. Why?

Tags: kernel, reboot

I regularly update my Trusty 3.13 kernel on Updates Manager notifications. As I do I such case, I remove the n-2 kernel just before upgrading so that my system remains with 2 kernel releases once the upgrade is done.

On last upgrade from 3.13.0-87 to 3.13.0-88, Updates Manager asked for reboot as usual, but once logged back in with -88, Update Manager asked again to reboot. Please, why ?

Comment: Did this happen once or is it a loop?

Comment: No it didn't, after 2nd reboot it was quiet again. I asked because I saw this behaviour in 3 PCs.

Comment: I have more info. This happened again to me today, several days after I installed 3.13.0-88: when I removed 3.13.0-86 (keeping 3.13.0-87 for safety as I usually do), nothing particular happened. But when I ran UpdateManager manually, I was prompted to reboot.

Answer (score 0):

From [How does Ubuntu keep track of the “System restart required” flag in motd?](https://serverfault.com/questions/92932/how-does-ubuntu-keep-track-of-the-system-restart-required-flag-in-motd) You can see which packages requested the reboot:

```
$ cat /var/run/reboot-required.pkgs 
linux-image-2.6.32-28-generic
dbus
network-manager
```

I try to remove old kernels before I do the reboot.  The removal of a kernel re-runs grub and triggers the reboot.